# Python argparse with optional positional and default None

Tags: python, argparse, python-3.9

Working with Python and `argparse`, trying to accomplish the following:

```bash
$> my_app
Namespace(positional=None)
$> my_app file.txt somedir
Namespace(positional=['file.txt', 'somedir'])
```

i.e., a positional argument of type list, whose default is None. I would expect the following code to accomplish this:

```py
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("positional", nargs='*', default=None)

print(p.parse_args())
```

But I get:

```bash
$> my_app
Namespace(positional=[])
$> my_app file.txt somedir
Namespace(positional=['file.txt', 'somedir'])
```

The rest of my code uses `None` as defaults for lists. If `None` is provided, the code select a sensible default. Thus passing `[]` is not an option.

The behavior of `argparse` does rather feel like a bug, but maybe I'm missing something. Any thoughts?

---

**Answer** (thx hpaulj) seems to be "as intended" to which I would add "completely unintuitively".

Comment: With `my_app`, the list of a strings that satisfies the `*` condition is empty, `[]`.  Unlike an `optional` where the `default` appears in the Namespace if the flag isn't used, your `positional` is always seen, regardless of the number of arguments.  If the default is not `None`, then is can appear in the Namespace (there's a special line of code that handles this exception).

Comment: "The rest of my code uses None as defaults for lists. If None is provided, the code select a sensible default. Thus passing [] is not an option." As the user of your program, how should I run it, if I want the list to be empty and **not** use the program's default?

Comment: The user is calling the command line interface and does not know about any internal functions. All he sees is the doc, which states: "Runs my_app on the provided files and folders. Defaults to the current working directory."

Comment: But thanks for the discussion, I think I should set the default to `['.']` to match my docstring!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is handled in

```
def _get_values(self, action, arg_strings):
    ...
    # when nargs='*' on a positional, if there were no command-line
    # args, use the default if it is anything other than None
    elif (not arg_strings and action.nargs == ZERO_OR_MORE and
          not action.option_strings):
        if action.default is not None:
            value = action.default
            self._check_value(action, value)
        else:
            # since arg_strings is always [] at this point
            # there is no need to use self._check_value(action, value)
            value = arg_strings
```

Normally the `default` is placed in the Namespace at the start of parsing.  During parsing that default is overwritten with value(s) provided by the user.  `optionals` are 'seen' when the right flag is used.  `positionals` are 'seen' when the right number of strings are present. Since '*' and '?' accept 0 strings, they will always be 'seen'.  Thus their defaults require special handling, if at all.

Comment: This seems rather unintuitive, considering Python's handling of default values. Consider the following: A function `do_something(dirs)` processes directories. If none was provided, the current directory is processed. The cli just feeds the positional into this function. The default is not applied. But thank you for tracking down the code!

Comment: Comments dont allow for fancy examples, but the function(s) go something like this: `process(dirs=None): if dirs=None: dirs=...` . The cli should then do: `process(dirs=args.dirs)`.

Comment: This is the other way around, though: you are expecting **the argument parser** to take an empty list (supplied by the user) and replace it with `None`, so that you can subsequently interpret `None` specially (in the Python idiomatic way). Going from `[]` to `None` is the opposite direction. More importantly, the UI design you propose doesn't seem Pythonic to me at all. After all, "special cases aren't special enough to break the rules", and "explicit is better than implicit". Zero just isn't that special of a number (of list elements).

Comment: We don't do design or subjective stuff in answers here, but personally my design advice is to use a named argument on the command line. Then `my_app -x foo bar` can translate to an `x` argument of `['foo', 'bar']`, `my_app -x` can translate to `[]`, and `my_app` can translate to a `None` which is re-translated (or, perhaps, *directly* to the default list).

Comment: I get your point about me technically wanting to convert from `[]` to `None` - but from a users perspective `my_app` is not a call with an empty list, rather a call with no argument at all. Besides: why go to the trouble of explicitly forbidding a `None` default... The use of optional named arguments seems to be rather clumsy.

Comment: Function arguments can be positional or keyword.  Only keyword arguments have a default.  A `*args` positional may be an empty list.   The `argparse` distinction between `positional` and `optional` is superficially similar, but it also inherits user expectations from C parsers, POSIX, and earlier python parsers, `getopt` and `optparse`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired behavior like this

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("positional", nargs='*', default=argparse.SUPPRESS)

print(p.parse_args(namespace=argparse.Namespace(positional=None)))
```

This prevents the arguments from appearing at all in the namespace which on turn causes the default namespace to take over.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal and clever usage of a default namespace. Didn't know this was a thing! I feel however that `if args.positional=[]: args.positional=None` is just as short and just as ugly/in need of documentation.